# Регистрация аккаунта продавца в Google Play (Украина)

Tags: android, google-play

Я хочу продавать приложения как частное лицо (это ведь возможно?). Интересуют следующие особенности при регистрации:

- Какое названии компании указывать? Свое имя и фамилию на транслите (у меня имя разработчика так же написано)?
- Какой адрес компании указывать? Проблема в том что этот адрес общедоступный и отображается на странице приложения. Поэтому свой домашний указывать не хочется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не касается API (то есть программирования), а потому [является вопросом не по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Arhad, [**разве**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2977/199934)? Спасибо.

Comment: @Arhad вопрос полезный потому что на тот момент я так и не смог быстро найти нужную мне информацию (если вы посмотрите на дату ответа - прошел почти месяц поисков). В крайнем случае переместить, но никак не закрывать. И да, публикацию (и как следствие - регистрацию в Google Play) тоже можно считать частью разработки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Итак, после общения с техподдержкой и другими разработчиками удалось выяснить вот что:

В названии компании можно указывать все что угодно, только если это название не занято кем-то ранее.

В качестве адреса нужно указывать **реальный** адрес, к которому есть доступ. Помимо адреса компании можно указывать адрес PO Box (абонентский ящик, по-нашему), в противном случае придется указывать свой фактический адрес. Увы, иначе никак.

PS: Во время гугления я несколько раз находил в Google Play приложения от частных разработчиков, на странице которых был указан их реальный адрес (включая номер дома и квартиры). Так что при отсутствии других вариантов - это единственный способ регистрации аккаунта продавца.